# HTML and CSS misunderstand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like someone to explain to me how the class `active-slide` works.

Code:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide active-slide">..</div>
<div class = "slide slide-feature">..</div>
<div class = "slide">..</div>
<div class = "slide">..</div>
```

and the class `slide` in the css gets the **`display:none`** property and it does no effect at all.

```
<div class="slide active-slide">..</div>
```

Comment: The meaning of order and, more importantly, _specificity_ in CSS is what you should go read up on.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all slides are `display: none` if only having the `slide` class. The `active-slide` class has `display:block` (or `inline-block`, or something other than `none`).  This is overriding `display:none`.

```
.slide {
    display: none; // says anything with class of .slide does not display
}
.slide.active-slide {
    display: block; // says override the display property for items with class of .slide and .active-slide
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `active-slide` class set's the specific slide to `display: block;` which makes it visible to the user.

Originally, all slides are set to `display: none;` and therefore they do not show. Only the slide with the `active-slide` class will show.